# MySQL Move old data between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. I am trying to move data that's older than 2 months to a different table, so I created this routine code:

```
BEGIN
         START TRANSACTION;

         DECLARE _limit_date DATETIME;
         SET _limit_date := DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH);

         INSERT
         INTO    UserDataHist
         SELECT  *
         FROM    UserData
         WHERE   DateTimeLocal < _limit_date;

         DELETE
         FROM    UserData
         WHERE   DateTimeLocal < _limit_date;

         COMMIT;
END
```

But that gives me an error somewhere in the following code:

```
DECLARE _limit_date DATETIME;
SET _limit_date := DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH);
```

Now I can't find a lot about routine code examples like mine, so I have no idea what is wrong!
Can someone tell me why I my code gives me an error?

Comment: Is your code in a stored program (procedure/function/event)?

Comment: In phpmyadmin I go to routines and when I want to add a procedure and add this code to it, it gives me an error, so I can't save the routine!

Comment: 'START TRANSACTION or BEGIN start a new transaction.' (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) - there is no begin transaction ALSO FOR UPDATE looks a bit lonely.

Comment: I updated my code, but still an error in the same part somewhere!?

Comment: Please review the manual - nb a DECLARE can only follow a BEGIN either move it to before the start transaction or include the work in a begin..end block.